# Assign current AKS resource and name to linux variables

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-service

I am running a script that requires the  resource group and name of current AKS client config. Previously configured with az aks get-credentials ...

Current script:
(I type AKS=something and RG=SOMETHING before running)

```
az aks update -g $RG -n $AKSNAME ...
```

Wanted script:
(I type nothing before running)

```
AKSNAME=$(what goes here?)
RG=$(what goes here?)
az aks update -g $RG -n $AKSNAME ...
```

How can I load RG and AKSNAME values automatically through a shell script?

EDIT:  I current assign the values to those variables by hand.  I want the script to find the values automatically, corresponding to the cluster in the current context e.g. which kubectl is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just get the credential via the command `az aks get-credentials ....` without parameter `--admin`, then you can get the cluster name like this:

```
AKSNAME=$(kubectl config current-context)
```

And if you use the parameter `--admin`, then you need to change the command like this:

```
AKSNAME=$(kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{.contexts[0].context.cluster}')
```

Then you can get the group name like this:

```
RG=$(az aks list --query "[?name == '$AKSNAME'].resourceGroup" -o tsv)
```